# Is it okay to remove code from a question that is unrelated to the problem?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179085/public-method-not-returning-value-c-sharp) question to fix the code indentation, but the question still contains a lot of code not related to the problem — three full classes.

In this case it's fairly obvious what parts of the code are related to the question, but I didn't want to delete parts of someone else's code, so I left a comment suggesting the author edits it down to a minimal, complete, verifiable example, with a link to the article.

What would have been the correct response?  It's attracted a lot of down and close votes, and while I don't think it's a very good question, I think it could at least have been fixed to the point it may not be closed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The correct response is to edit the question such that it doesn't suck.

Ideally, when you're done the question can be effectively answered without annoying people and chewing up lots of time with irrelevance.

Do what you can to make that happen. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20828838/revisions

And here are some guidelines for including code in questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So as someone reviewing suggested edits, what should I do in that same case? I often lean towards rejection, because while indeed it may improve the question, one could argue it's deviating form the author's intent.

Comment: I really don't support editing question *meaning* in anyway - includes removing sentences, code or anything else.

Comment: Make the call based on how you understand the effects of the specific edit you're reviewing, @McAdam331: if it breaks the question or deviates from what the author meant to ask, then reject it. If it removes irrelevant cruft to let the author's intended question shine through, then approve it. It's impossible to make a good call on such an edit without taking the time to understand its effects.

Comment: There are plenty of questions where the only sensible alternative is deleting the question, @TomášZato. If you're comfortable with that, so be it.

Comment: @Shog9 definitely something I will keep in mind. I usually take into consideration the editors comment also, to see what was going through their mind. If I'm unsure, or it's changes to code in a language I'm not familiar enough with to make that decision, I will skip it.

Comment: @McAdam331 that seems quite sensible of you.

Comment: @Shog9 could you please update https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code#260246 with this guidance?

Comment: I agree with you but you may want to limit the scope of this answer to **non-suggested edits** because I found a few meta posts over the years that say that edit reviewers are in the right to reject more or less any code edit because reviewers are not expected to know anything about the tag in question.

Comment: There's a super-useful "skip" button for situations where you've no idea what you're reading, @jrh. Wish more reviewers were aware of it.

Comment: @Shog9 FYI [Do not edit a post:... to add code, remove code, or change existing code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362684/4975230)

Answer (score 4):

When editing questions, it is important to make the question as clear as possible.  A clear question helps highlight the confusion or unknown information of the original posting.  To that end, I see two cases that apply to your meta question:

1. The question has significant extraneous code that is not needed.  The person asking the question has simply posted all of their application.

In these cases, editing is encouraged, and a comment should be left indicating that what the poster has put into their question is basically useless.

2. The question has extra code but it is clear that the person posting does not know the relevant code to post, as part of their confusion comes from not understanding how to narrow down the problem.

When this happens, I think it *is* best to leave the irrelevant code in place.  This enables people answering the question to have better context as to what is being asked (since the root problem is a lack of understanding of the general structure), and may allow for a teaching moment where the person who posted the question can learn how to debug things more thoroughly.