# Is the language in this edit rejection too strong?

Tags: discussion, edits

I made my first edit today to remove a tag. It was ultimately approved, but I received a rejection vote with the following reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

When I read that I thought: "You're a jerk. You really didn't need to say 'even a little bit easier'."

Then another rejection vote came in with the same reason, so I realized that the first reason was a canned comment and not a cranky reviewer.

I appreciate that SO provides a reason for the rejection, but what I was taken aback by were the phrases "even a little bit" and "completely".  Adding that verbiage seems to make the tone needlessly strong. I'd add that emphasis if I was trying to make someone feel bad for what they had done.  The following reason gives the same idea without the 'tone' just by removing the extraneous phrases:

> This edit does not make the post easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either superfluous or actively harm readability.

(Never mind that the word 'completely' in 'completely superfluous' is, itself, superfluous. ;) )

Clearly this post in the realm of 'subjective', but am I being thin-skinned or are there other areas in SO where you feel that the language has crossed over from 'firm' to 'did I just told that I'm dumb'?

Comment: I wouldn't mind having _"even a little bit"_ and _"completely"_ removed from that message. I agree that those are not necessary to convey the message. Removing those would make the notification a little more professional... The side effect would be that this message would no linger apply when a suggested edit only made the post a  _little_ bit easier to read.

Comment: The wording is explicit like this to distinguish it from the old "too minor" reject reason, which got removed because the powers that be decided we should now embrace even the most minor of edits with open arms. I'd be all for changing the _intention_ behind the reject reason to once again reject minor edits; something like bumping a year-old bad question back to the front page because some "I"s have been capitalized or similar minor fixes is simply not a positive contribution at all. But simply changing the wording to be "nice" accomplishes nothing.

Comment: ["It's a hostile _action_... Sadly, that's sometimes necessary..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242160/165773)

Comment: @gnat Thank you.  I tried searching to see if someone else had brought this up and wasn't successful.  You've pointed me to the discussion I was looking for.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yeah, the edit reason aggressively emphasises that the edit is utterly worthless, in firm language. I think this is probably intentional, and aimed at preventing reviewers from using the reason to reject minor-but-helpful edits. [Shog's commentary upon the hostile wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242160/200582) corroborates this idea to some extent.

Some background: the old "too minor" rejection reason was [removed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/) shortly after a [heated argument](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site/253530) about whether it was ever right to use it. Many folks liked being able to reject edits for being minor because they felt that such edits wasted the time of reviewers overseeing the pointless, petty brass-polishing of suggested editors; others, me included, thought that this was silly and that any suggestion that makes a post better should be accepted, even if it is minor. Judging by the votes, most people on Meta are on the pro-minor-edits side, but there are still many people opposed to them.

If the new close reason were worded less strongly, it is likely that it would be used to reject edits that are helpful but minor. Such rejections are *still a problem* even with the stern wording, as evidenced by [your helpful edit removing a misapplied tag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7178058) drawing two such rejection votes. But hopefully the stern wording deters some people from rejecting helpful minor edits, and that - in my opinion at least - is a good thing.

Comment: Given this, I'd suggest that there should be a bit of a split between the sum of the wording presented to the reviewer, which should be quite clear on the standards for using that rejection reason, and the wording presented to the editor, which can and should be more diplomatic.

Comment: Part of the dispute over minor, fairly meaningless edits is that they bump the post to the front page, which forces newer posts off. While that may seem minor, I recently encountered a front page that was almost entirely old posts, because a (fairly high rep) user was simply going through and adding a tag to a bunch of very old posts, and the activity caused about 90% of the front page content off the page (and the remaining 10% to the bottom). Hardly a useful effect, and it would be exacerbated if tons of minor edits changing lowercase i to uppercase I were allowable.

Comment: @KenWhite good point - I always forget about the front page because personally I almost never use it at all, and only get reminded that it exists when the people who do use it complain about actions that are filling it with stuff they don't want.

Comment: And such minor edits are usually opinion based. You can get in a fight over a single word or a couple of spaces, and I think editing them cause more noise than added value.

Comment: [Obviously](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7126727) [some people](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7126728) [didn't get the memo.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7170466)

Comment: @Braiam: I don't believe that the edit you have linked to that I rejected improved the readability of the question at all. Sure it changed the style of it, but I believed that this was merely changing it for the sake of it when it was already perfectly readable as is. From what I understand, if the post does not provide a *net* improvement in readability, it should be rejected.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I wasn't going to address the specific edits in Braiam's comment, but for the record: I totally agree with you. [The edit you rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7170466) also removed a helpful, clarifying paragraph and (further) broke the question's grammar; if anything, I'd've given it a custom rejection reason pointing out that it actively caused harm in addition to being utterly pointless. I've rolled it back.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy if that was the case, you shouldn't have used "no improvement whatsoever" instead "conflict with the author intention" (also it conflicted with a previous edit). Either way, my edit, just removing the "Have you ever encountered such a cases?" is an improvement in and out itself, since that only invites people saying "me too" (as it said in the edit comment) and made the question [suck less overall](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278014/792066).

Comment: @MarkAmery now you have destroyed the question re-adding the "Have you ever encountered such a cases?", what's the point of having that utterly useless phrase there?

Comment: @Braiam No, I've edited it further. The rollback button takes the edit back to a particular revision; I've then added my own edit on top of that. Aside: while a silly throwaway question in broken English at the end of a post is a bad thing that should be altered or nuked, I think it's a little hyperbolic to say that it "destroys the question". Plenty of posts on Stack Overflow are useful despite containing language errors and worthless cruft; likewise, edits can be helpful *on net* despite adding such things, or harmful *on net* despite removing such things.