# When should we discuss rejection of a legitimate edit on meta?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I recently began participating actively and noticed the rejection of [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17509615) when exploring all the tabs on my profile. Reviewers seem to believe that I changed the intent of the question, but really, I just fixed a bit of formatting and removed some "fluff", including some garbage output dumped by the framework's exception handler—based in part on recommendations<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278014/5209322)[[2]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/5209322)</sup> I read here on meta.

Naturally, I checked here to learn if I could contest or discuss the rejection, and the answers that I found suggest that I need to post on meta. Is it really worth starting a discussion for every instance an edit is *mistakenly* rejected? I feel like it may be overkill to start a new thread whenever this happens. Assuming rejection of a *high-quality* edit, are there cases when a meta discussion is more valuable or justifiable than simply ignoring the rejection?

I think I can guess why my edit was rejected—cutting out the unrelated exception text makes it appear as if I changed code relevant to the question when not read closely. I'm interested to know if contesting rejections like this adds value, or if I'm just adding to the noise. For what it's worth, I found the question through a search, so other readers may benefit from the edit. Should I contest rejected edits here in the future when justified? Is there some (probably subjective) threshold I should consider before doing so?

**Update**

Many thanks to the users who reviewed the rejected edit and offered thoughts and suggestions. Your comments helped me better understand the review process. Although I do seek and appreciate this feedback, I included information about the edit mainly to provide context. I'd like to direct focus to the primary question, rephrased below:

*Are there any approximate community-accepted characteristics that qualify a valid-but-rejected edit for discussion on meta?*

I'm guessing that some candidates for meta review may be too minor to bother with. Or does the site take the stance that any missed opportunity for improvement and learning is worth revisiting? I want to avoid spamming meta in the future with these, so I'd like to get a feeling for which edits I should consider posting for review. As a frame of reference, where does the suggested edit in this question fall on the scale?

Comment: I'd love to know where on meta you were recommended that you should remove information from the error, be it "garbage" or not

Comment: @Nick - I hear you--I can't imagine that anyone would recommend that explicitly. I removed the text in a genuine effort to improve the clarity of the post based on my familiarity with the framework. The extra text actively distracts from the question and I didn't decide to remove it lightly. Should I refrain from doing so in the future?

Comment: i think the changes that you've made are a subtle improvement but an important one, others may disagree with me but the ***exact*** truth i find very important when reading peoples meta posts. As for your question, i think *contesting* may not be the right word, but *discussing* your reasoning and trying to achieve an understanding of the actual result is certainly worth doing, although minor cases can probably be discussed in SOCVR (someone object that if im wrong), I probably wouldve rejected the edit as the improvements are minor and there are other posts which need proper editing. ...

Comment: ... It has been known for mistakes to happen so if you do start a discussion theres every possibility the edit will be made by a 2k+ user

Comment: @NickA [from Shog of course](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278014/792066)

Comment: That was overall a pretty solid edit, but you removed what certainly *looks* like non-trivial pieces of text from the error message, so I suspect the reviewers rejected it on that basis. Maybe you're enough of an expert in the relevant technology to know that the stuff you removed there is well and truly fluff, but you cannot expect all reviewers to have the same level of technical knowledge. I certainly wouldn't.

Comment: @Cody - I'll make sure to be very clear if I ever edit code in the future! Is the edit comment the right place?

Comment: @CyRossignol yes SOCVR is the SO close vote reviewers room

Comment: If you're not sure ask about meta what you could have did better, if you're sure of what you suggested, move on :)

Comment: @NickA I don't see edit reviewing discussion on [SOCVR's FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq), and their scope is pretty clearly defined. Have you seen people do this in the past? I'm not sure if it's a good idea to stretch the purpose of the room without clearing it with those guys first, unless it's intended to be a general "ask high rep users minor things about site cleanup/moderation" room. (Might be some value in that but as far as I know we don't have a room like that right now.)

Comment: @jrh I'm not sure,ive done it a couple times on occasion for **very** minor 1 sentence answer questions, thats why i wanted a high rep common user of that room to object if need be

Comment: [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) is open for discussion about moderation on SO. However we're not a *something turned out not the way I hoped for and now I need a mob to rectify stuff*. But if you come with a neutral request to seek help in preventing your next edit being rejected as well, by all means, join the room. We have a broad set of regulars that all have done their fair part of editing, both in posts and wiki's and we have all had our rejects, rollbacks and edit mishaps, so plenty of folks around to exchange ideas and learn a bit. /cc @jrh

Comment: I think the ideal rejection edit to bring to meta for discussion would be a rejected edit on a high-profile (active with lots of views/votes) post that attempted to fix what the editor perceived as a significant problem with the post, rather than just routine formatting or cleanup. Starting from that point, the lower the visibility of the post, and the lower the importance of the edit, the less important it is to contest the edit rejection.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - This makes good sense. Thanks for the direct answer. I'm sure this also applies to most contributions besides rejected edits.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no process to "contest" rejections. You can (as you did here) start a discussion about a particular change where you don't know or strongly disagree with the reason for rejection (and it is not rejected by the OP), which may in turn lead to a similar edit being applied to the question.

Note that the OP of the post has a binding vote on edits - so if they feel your edit is worthwhile they can accept it at any time.

About this particular edit - it removed what to most reviewers *looks like code*  and this in general makes an edit <strike>not valid</strike> a strong candidate for rejection. Adding explicit info in the edit comment about why you removed that *could* have helped, but even than you removed part of the compiler's error message - which does not feel like a good change to me. Additionally you left the boilerplate text "I have searched over the internet but no working solution to this" instead of removing it along with all the other fluff.

As a side note - the edit was on an old low value post - even if you decided to answer and edit the question you did not find it useful (there are 0/0 votes on the post now). You may want to spend your time on questions that at least you consider of reasonable quality and useful.

Comment: "it removed what to most reviewers looks like code and this is in general makes edit not valid" [citation needed]

Comment: @Braiam https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

Comment: ... What part of that 3 pages long is that?

Comment: Thanks @Alexei - This was helpful. I'll remember to leave a very clear comment if I ever modify code in the future. I left the bit of fluff you describe because I read another answer that cautioned against removing details that convey an asker's skill level. Looking back, this bit probably doesn't do that. I only contributed to this particular answer because I found it through a search engine, so I wanted to leave something behind in case someone else did.